# Kivy: Image scrolling

Tags: python, kivy

I have a simple code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class TutorialApp(App):
    def build(self):
        l=Image(source='kivy.jpg', keep_ratio=True)
        return l
if __name__ == "__main__":
    TutorialApp().run()
```

I get the following result:

[image]

I want to image width equal to the width of the screen (without losing the aspect ratio).  I also need vertical scrolling (to view full image).

The result should be something like this:

[image]

How to do it?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make an image or anything scrollable, use [ScrollView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window


class TutorialApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sv = ScrollView(size=Window.size)
        l = Image(
            source='kivy.jpg',
            size_hint=(None, None),
            keep_ratio=True,
            size=Window.size
        )
        sv.add_widget(l)
        return sv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TutorialApp().run()
```

Setting `size_hint` to (None, None) and then defining fixed `size` allows to keep the original window size, even if it is changes in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.scatter import ScatterPlane

class MyScatterPlane(App):
    def build(self):
        sp = ScatterPlane(scale=1)
        img = Image(source='ccc.bmp', pos=(0,0), size=Window.size)
        sp.add_widget(img)

        return sp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyScatterPlane().run()
```