# ScrollView in Tabs kivy/KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

**Question was updated**
I have a code:

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDToolbar:
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: x]]
        title: "Smart home & its components"

    MDTabs:
        id: tabs
        on_tab_switch: app.on_tab_switch(*args)
        Tab:
            text: 'Smart home'
            FitImage:
                source: 'smarthome.png'
        Tab:
            text: 'Smart garage'
            ScrollView:
                do_scroll_x: False
                FitImage:
                    size_hint: (None, None)
                    size: root.size
                    source: 'garage.jpg'
                Button:
                    size_hint: (None, None)
                    size: (100, 100)
                Button:
                    size_hint: (None, None)
                    size: (100, 100)


<Tab>:
'''


class Tab(FloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    pass


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_tab_switch(self, instance_tabs, instance_tab, instance_tab_label, tab_text):
        pass


Example().run()

'''


class Tab(FloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    pass


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_tab_switch(self, instance_tabs, instance_tab, instance_tab_label, tab_text):
        pass


Example().run()
```

part of code:

```py
Button:
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (100, 100)
Button:
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (100, 100)
```

When i run the code without this part, i get scrollable image in the second tab, but when i run code with this part of code, i get error.

Error:

```py
Exception: ScrollView accept only one widget
```

I understand why i got error and that ScrollView accept only one widget, but if it possible, how to put Buttons under my scrollable image?

Thank u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ScrollView:
    do_scroll_x: False
    
    MDList:
    
        FitImage:
            size_hint: (None, None)
            size: root.size
            source: 'garage.jpg'
        Button:
            size_hint: (None, None)
            size: (100, 100)
        Button:
            size_hint: (None, None)
            size: (100, 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase

KV = '''
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDToolbar:
        title: "Example Tabs Toolbar"

    MDTabs:
        id: tabs
        on_tab_switch: app.on_tab_switch(*args)
        
        Tab:
            text: 'Smart home'
            source: 'image.png'
                
        Tab:
            text: 'Smart garage'
            source: 'image.png'

<Tab>:
    orientation: "vertical"

    FitImage:
        source: root.source

    ScrollView:
    
        MDList:
            id: box

'''


class Tab(MDBoxLayout, MDTabsBase):
    source = StringProperty()


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        self.root.ids.tabs.switch_tab('Smart garage')

    def on_tab_switch(self, instance_tabs, instance_tab, instance_tab_label, tab_text):
        instance_tab.ids.box.clear_widgets()
        for i in range(20):
            instance_tab.ids.box.add_widget(
                MDLabel(text=f"Text {i}", halign="center")
            )


Example().run()
```

Comment: when i run the code, 

i get this: self.dispatch('on_start')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/soft_and_code/ph-dl/kivy/shareit/filesharerkivy/filesharekivy v1.3/fuckingproject/main.py", line 51, in on_start
     self.root.ids.tabs.switch_tab('Smart garage')
   File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'MDTabs' object has no attribute 'switch_tab'

Comment: When i run the code without on_start method, code works, but  scrolling doesn't work, and images(garage image and smarthome image) not in full size(images has not size like in a photo).

Comment: Reinstall KivyMD library from master branch - https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD

Comment: ScrollView works, but image not in full size(images has not size like in a photo). Can u fix it?

Comment: Is possible add garage image to the ScrollView widget?

Comment: If the image will take up all the space, where do you want to place the ScrollView???

Comment: ScrollView will be contains image. Image will be individual element of ScrollView widget.

Comment: If image will be take up all screen, we can just scroll it.
100% of the Screen is not 100% of the ScrollView

Comment: The question should be asked differently in such a case. **How to create a scrollable image?** - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35626320/kivy-image-scrolling