# Kivy ScrollView code error with scrollbars (or bug?)

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview, scrollbar

I'm playing around with a Kivy Scrollview, adding scrollbars, etc, and getting a strange crash. I don't specifically think it's a *bug*, it's probably some configuration element on Scrollviews that I'm missing, but who knows?

Given this code:

```
"""
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35626320/kivy-image-scrolling
"""
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window

class TutorialApp(App):
    def build(self):

        some_img = Image(source='/home/data/map/Map_07C.jpg', size_hint=(None, None),
                         keep_ratio=True, size=(Window.width * 2, Window.height * 2))
        sv = ScrollView(size=Window.size, bar_width=50,
                        scroll_type=['bars', 'content'], effect_cls='ScrollEffect')
        sv.add_widget(some_img)

        return sv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TutorialApp().run()
```

if I click or touch the Scrollbars in any way, I get this error:

```
   File "kivy_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/uix/scrollview.py", line 908, in on_scroll_move
     self.effect_x.update(touch.x)
   File "kivy_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/effects/scroll.py", line 116, in update
     self.displacement += abs(val - self.history[-1][1])
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

However - if I first click the bitmap being scrolled, I can use the scrollbars with no problem.

So what's up? Is there some Scrollview configuration I'm missing? (It took me a while to even find the `scroll_type` option to enable the bars, at first I could only mouse-drag the bitmap). Or is it a bug - given that it's referencing `history[-1]`, maybe that doesn't exist yet?

Comment: Technically there's a workaround - I'll just tell the client, "Every time you run this app, be sure to click in the center, *before* daring to use the scrollbars". :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it's a bug. Just searched the Kivy repo on Github, found:

[Effects Scroll Exception](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/2935)

The link does have a "workaround" patch, that you can manually apply to the installed library. Just tested the patch, it fixes my problem. Basically puts a try/except/return block around the line with `history[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

technically is a bug but we can note from the desktop and mobile apps that they use different `scroll_type=['bars', 'content']` in the desktop app we use `bars`
and in the mobile app we use `content` so the bug only occurs when we use two types of `scroll_type` so we can say that the `scrollview` does not design to use two type of `scroll_type` in the same time

Comment: Maybe, but the `scroll_type` variable is designed to take a *list* of parameters, not a single parameter. And it does work (for me, on a PC) with both types of scrolling - if I either do mouse-scrolling first (thus populating the history variable), or apply the patch.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is calling a function on_touch_down that checks the mouse's x-position and changes the scroll type to either only ['Bars'] or only ['Content'] accordingly. Note, I set mine to check Window.width - 12 as that is the width of scroll bar that I use. Default is 2.

```
# tutorial.kv
<SV>:
    on_touch_down: self.check_pos()
    bar_width: 12


# main.py
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

class SV(ScrollView):
    def check_pos(self):
        if Window.mouse_pos[0] <= (Window.width - 12):
            self.scroll_type = ['content']
        else:
            self.scroll_type = ['bars']
```